# Show that $\ker (P + Q - ΡQ) \subset\ker Ρ \cap \ker Q$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following exercise to do : $\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{ran}$

> Let $Ρ$ and $Q$ be projections. Show that $PQ = QΡ$ if and only if $Ρ + Q - ΡQ$ is a
> projection. If this is the case, then $\ran (P + Q - ΡQ) = \ran P + \ran Q$ and
> $\ker (P + Q - ΡQ) = \ker Ρ \cap \ker Q$.

I have proved the both direction of the first part of the theorem. I have proved $\ran(P + Q - ΡQ) \subset \ran P + \ran Q$. I have also proved that $\ker Ρ \cap \ker Q \subset \ker(P + Q - ΡQ)$.

Only remaining things are $\ker (P + Q - ΡQ) \subset \ker Ρ \cap ker Q$ and $\ran P + \ran Q \subset \ran(P + Q - ΡQ)$. How does one prove  these two? And do I need to show my try for the other things mentioned that I have fully proved?

Comment: I decided to look at this exercise myself, but am having trouble showing that $P+Q-PQ$ being a projection implies that $PQ=QP.$ May I ask how you showed that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Px+Qx-PQx=0$ then $P(Px+Qx-PQx)=0$  which gives $Px+PQx-PQx=0$ or $Px=0$. Hence $\ker(P+Q-PQ) \subset \ker (P)$. Just interchange $P$ and $Q$ to see that  $\ker(P+Q-PQ) \subset \ker (Q)$.

Let $y \in Ran (P)+Ran Q$. then $y=Px+Qy$ for some $x$ and $y$. Now check that $(P+Q-PQ)(Px+Qy)=Px+Qy=y$. So $y \in Ran (P+Q-PQ)$. [Use the fact that $PQPx=(QP)Px=QPx$]